# Break ansible k/v variable with hasicorp vault loop logic in value

Tags: python, ansible, yaml

Can someone help me to find out if it is possible to break ansible variable with loop logic in value?
Lets say that I have variable with loop logic for hashicorp vault in value inside group_vars yaml, like that:

```
     some_value: "{{ lookup('hashi_vault', 'secret=secret/hello:value auth_method=userpass username=myuser password=mypas url=http://myvault:8200') | default(‘something’, true)}}"
```

And I tried to make this looks more readable, like that:

```
some_value: >- "{{ lookup('hashi_vault', 
               'secret=secret/hello:value 
                auth_method=userpass 
                username=myuser password=mypas 
                url=http://myvault:8200') | default(‘something’, true)}}"
```

Break the loop line with **>** and **|** options. But this way convert all loop query to string, and paste in debug as sentence.

Any ideas how I can break lines without breaking logic?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Very briefly (see docs below for more info)

`>` is the yaml folded scalar block marker. It expects a string starting on the next line with indentation. Single new lines at end of lines will be transformed to spaces. Blank line will be kept as new line chars

`-` is the "no new line at end" chomping indicator for the scalar block.

A possible transformation of your expression into a folded block could be:

```
some_value: >-
  {{
  lookup('hashi_vault', 
  'secret=secret/hello:value 
  auth_method=userpass 
  username=myuser
  password=mypas 
  url=http://myvault:8200')
  | default(‘something’)
  }}
```

There are many possible variations.

Meanwhile, to keep this even more readable, I would cut it in two different variables.

```
hv_params: >-
  secret=secret/hello:value 
  auth_method=userpass 
  username=myuser
  password=mypas 
  url=http://myvault:8200

some_value: "{{ lookup('hashi_vault', hv_params) | default('something') }}"
```

Refs:

- https://learnxinyminutes.com/docs/yaml/
- https://yaml-multiline.info/

Comment: Do you get the expected value with your original lookup definition ? The above is the exact translation of that line (unless there is something right in front of my eyes I don't see...)

Comment: My fault. Forgot about flag "true" for default value.